# Fail to deploy a kubernetes application with the Rancher

Tags: kubernetes, ingress, rancher, traefik, kubernetes-on-premises

I am trying to deploy a kubenetes application in a on-premise infrastructure, but there is something wrong with the "Deploy", "Service", and "Ingress" configuration files.

I am using the Traefik as an ingress controller. Thus, when I deploy my new application it is shown normally in the Traefik dashboard, but I am not able to access this application from Port 80.

Here, the Panel of the Traefik

[image: Here, the Panel of the Traefik]

My Environment

Rancher: 2.7

Kubectl

- Client Version: v1.25.4
- Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
- Server Version: v1.24.9

Ingress Controller

- Traefic 2.9

No LSB modules are available.

- Distributor ID: Ubuntu
- Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- Release: 22.04
- Codename: jammy

**Here, as my files are configured**

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: whoami5
  # namespace: whoami5
  labels:
    allow.http: "false"
    application: whoami5
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      application: whoami5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        application: whoami5
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: whoami5
        image: jwilder/whoami
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
        securityContext:
          privileged: true


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: whoami5
  # namespace: whoami5
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80 # Porta a ser exposta pelo SERVICE
    targetPort: 8000 # Porta que a aplicação está rodando no POD
  selector:
    application: whoami5


---
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: whoami5
  annotations:
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class.enabled: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls.certresolver: default
spec:
  # ingressClassName: traefik-ingress
  rules:
    - host: appv1.rancher.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: whoami5
                port: 
                  number: 80
```

At the end, I configured my local hosts file to resolve the DNS.

I added:

```
192.168.0.2 appv1.rancher.com
```

One more point is that: when I use the `hostPort`  I can access the application normally, but I imagine that there is another way to do it.

Comment: What's the problem exactly, what do you see: timeout, refused, ...? You mention connecting to port 80: did you try 443/https? We're sure your test containers are listening on port 8000, and not loopback-only (add livenessProbe, in doubt)? How's your Traefik configured, are we sure its ports 80/443 are exposed on that 192.168.0.2 address? Your Ingress/Service/Deployments looks OK from what I can see. Maybe try removing port 80/8000 translation, have your Service listening on 8000 directly/fix ingress accordinly? We're sure SDN works? From traefik pod, try to curl app pod. Please edit your post

Comment: Thanks, reading your comments, I realized that I was using http instead https to access my application. I Just replaced it and worked :-)